# return unix-timestamp format for datetime formatted field in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `Message` model like this :

```
class Message extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'message_id';
    protected $dates      = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'receiver_deleted_at', 'sender_deleted_at', 'sender_read_at', 'receiver_read_at'];
}
```

As you can see there are some date fields that hold dates as **DATETIME(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)** format.

But I want when get an instance of model all date fields convert to **unix-timestamp** format and then return.

I know that can use accessor like this for every field :

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute()
{
    dd(strtotime($this->attributes['created_at']));
    return strtotime($this->attributes['created_at']);
}
```

But in this case I must define a function like above for each field.

But I want an easier way that force model to return date fields as unix-timestamp format.

Comment: Accessors take care of the conversion to a Carbon instance which is an extension of default DateTime. So, `$this->created_at->format('U');` should work.

Comment: @TomLank., I want when call an instance of model converted format returned

Answer (score 10):

```php
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'timestamp',
    'updated_at' => 'timestamp'
];
```

In model just add these cast to get unix timestamp

Answer (score 1):

You can override the :

```
protected function getDateFormat()
{
 return 'U';
}
```

OR

Use timestamp property for each column:

```
$model->created_at->timestamp
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#timestamps

Comment: I added `getDateFormat` function but got this error : `Trailing data`