# Get Unix timestamp in laravel

Tags: laravel, unix-timestamp

I am storing created_at and updated_at as unix timestamp

for that i add following line to my modal its working fine.

```
class Test extends Model
{
    protected $dateFormat = 'U';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','question_id','answer',
    ];
}
```

but problem is when i retrieve record its give me readable format instead of unix timestamp so how i get value as store in database i.e(1593624368).
in database i use int(11) data-type for created_at and updated_at

```
created_at: 2020-07-01T17:45:03.000000Z,
updated_at: 2020-07-02T08:53:14.000000Z,
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return unix-timestamp format for datetime formatted field in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558710/return-unix-timestamp-format-for-datetime-formatted-field-in-laravel)

Comment: @mrhn may be no because i set create_at n update_at datatype as int(11) and i have many model i just put here one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use Laravel [Date Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting)

For your case:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'timestamp',
    'updated_at' => 'timestamp',
];
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: check update, test in Tinker and get proper format, in my case 1581346827