# laravel how to return unix-timestamps format in number/string format?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-8, datetime-format

Iam using Laravel  8

i made all steps to change `table->timestamp()` to `unix-timstamp` but its return in '2022-10-10T21:09:28.000000Z'

in Model.php

```
class Post extends Model
{
    HasFactory;
    protected $dateFormat = 'U';
}
```

in create_post_table.php

```
$table->unsignedInteger('created_at');
$table->unsignedInteger('updated_at');
```

result in data base:

[image]

return response()->json result:

[image]

i need to return in **'1665434137'** format ??

Comment: use ```strtotime``` function

Answer (score 0):

found answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558710/return-unix-timestamp-format-for-datetime-formatted-field-in-laravel)

in modal.php add

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'timestamp',
    'updated_at' => 'timestamp'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please follow these steps :

in your migration file ,change the

```
$table->unsignedInteger('created_at');
$table->unsignedInteger('updated_at');
```

to

```
$table->timestamps();
```

it will automatically create two columns in your table

Also please drop $casts and $dataFormat in your model.php file ,you don't need them anymore .

Finaly to achieve your result it is enough to do this :

```
Model->created_at->timestamp
Model->updated_at->timestamp
```

Notice the Model in above code should be replaced with the model object  you have , for example :

```
Post::find(1)->created_at->timestamp
```

or any other method of post object .